# My getline function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c++, getline

Sorry, still a beginner to coding.

I have this included in the block of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
```

Basically, I'm attempting to create a function that will store line by line, the data into a structure with 4 arrays of [200]. Here is my code,

```
struct AccountInfo {
    string account[200];
    int pin[200];
    string name[200];
    long double amount[200];
};

AccountInfo storeAccount(AccountInfo tabs[]) {
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("AccountInfo.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < myfile.eof(); i++)
    {
     getline(myfile, tabs[i].account);
     getline(myfile, tabs[i].pin);
     getline(myfile, tabs[i].name);
     getline(myfile, tabs[i].amount);
    }
}
```

All my getline's have this error message "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list"

If someone can help me out, that would be fantastic!

Comment: You really intend that each `AccountInfo` contains an array of two hundred distinct strings, two hundred integral values, two hundred names, and two hundred ammounts (sic)?

Comment: @Peter maybe they are a beginner genius and they know they will be parsing only the individual arrays at a time later on and want to take advantage of caching... :o

Comment: @FantasticMrFox   Uh hu.   Maybe one day it will rain beer while pigs are flying too.    My previous question is actually a hint for the OP about about the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The `getline()` function needs to receive in the second argument an `std::string`.
The compiler tells you that there is no such function that matches the argument list you've provided:

These are not strings:

1. array of `string`
2. array of `int`
3. array of `long double`

Also, when you pass a C-array to a function, it is recommended to pass its size, so if you iterate it internally, you could check that you're not exceeding its boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a struct of 4 arrays[200], you should create a struct of single values and then an array of AccountInfo[200]. This is what your method uses.

The code should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct AccountInfo {
    string account;
    int pin;
    string name;
    long double amount;
} AcountInfo_[200];

void storeAccount(AccountInfo tabs[]) {
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("AccountInfo.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < myfile.eof(); i++)
    {
     string pin;
     string amount;
     getline(myfile, tabs[i].account);
     getline(myfile, pin);
     tabs[i].pin = stoi(pin);
     getline(myfile, tabs[i].name);
     getline(myfile, amount); 
     tabs[i].amount = stof(amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

scanf() might be an easier option.

```
freopen("AccountInfo.txt", "r", stdin);
AccountInfo storeAccount(AccountInfo tabs[]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < myfile.eof(); i++) {
      scanf(myfile, &tabs[i].account);
      scanf(myfile, &tabs[i].pin);
      scanf(myfile, &tabs[i].name);
      scanf(myfile, &tabs[i].amount);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the pointer.